# Get Base 64 Encoding of File Object

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64

I have been on a mission the last few days, and the small part of that which is causing me to stumble is that I need to get the base64 encoding of a local binary file. I can ready the file (below), but I'm not sure if there are any methods, etc for getting the base64 encoding of the file now that I 'have' the file.

Any thoughts? I am a total noob when it comes to this :/ I've seen a few examples but non have worked for me and they seem overly complicated for this.

Restrictions: Must be client side! Must be IE 8 compatible.

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getsize()
{
    var myObject, afile, size;
    myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    afile = myObject.GetFile("C:\\test.txt)
    size = afile.Size;
    alert("The size of the file is:" + size);
}

</script>
Get the size for the file "test.txt"
<form name="myForm">
<input type="Button" value="Get Size" onClick='getsize()'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```